Variational calculus of Einstein-Hilbert action in general relativity
In his text, Einstein Gravity in a Nutshell, Zee defines Einstein-Hilbert action as follows(p. 346).
$$
S_{Einstein-Hilbert} \equiv \frac{1}{16\pi G} \int d^{4}x\sqrt{-g(x)}R(x)\cdots(1)
$$
In (1), $g(x)$ stands for the determinant of $g_{\mu\nu}$ regarded as a D-by-Dmatrix, and $R(x)$ means the scalar curvature.
Then, Zee varies the action with respect to $g_{\mu\nu}$, defining a tensor with two upper indices $K^{\mu\nu}$.
$$
\delta I = \delta \int d^{4}x \sqrt{-g(x)}R(x) \equiv \int d^{4}x\sqrt{-g(x)} K^{\mu\nu}(x)\delta g_{\mu\nu}(x) \cdots(2)
$$
(the constant omitted.)
According to Zee, therefore, $K^{\mu \nu}=0$.
I can understand that Zee has varied $g_{\mu \nu}$ in $R(x)$ in the second in (2) denoting the varied amount of $R(x)$ by $K^{\mu \nu} \delta g_{\mu \nu}$ in the third in (2).
However, it seems to me that Zee has not varied $g_{\mu \nu}$ in $\sqrt{-g(x)}$ in second in (2). $g(x)$ stands for the determinant of $g_{\mu\nu}$ regarded as a D-by-Dmatrix.
How could Zee conduct variational calculus in (2) without varying $g_{\mu \nu}$ in $\sqrt{-g(x)}$?

Zee most likely did vary. Taking variation of $\sqrt{-g}$ with respect to $g^{\mu \nu}$ gives you $-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-g} (g_{\mu \nu} \delta g^{\mu \nu})$ (see) and varying with respect to $g_{\mu \nu}$ should leave you with something similiar

I appreciate your useful suggestion. Thank you.
